# foreign key value not showing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

Let say I have 2 tables.

```
student_tbl = student_id(PK)
              student_name

officers_tbl = officer_id(PK)
               officer_name
               student_id(FK)
```

I have an autocomplete form with data from the student_tbl. Once the user  selects a student name from the autocomplete form, a hidden input will have a value which is the id of the selected student. After serializing the form,

```
    [stud_id] => Array
    (
        [1] => 400
        [2] => 404
        [3] => 423
        [4] => 462
        [5] => 401
        [6] => 413
        [7] => 414
        [8] => 409
        [9] => 403
        [10] => 0
    )

      //others
```

When stud_id = 0, insert student name to officer_name and NULL to student_id. 
When stud_id != 0, insert NULL to name and stud_id in student_id.

After submitting the form, in my database, only the NULL is inserted.

[image: After submitting the form]

**officers_tbl**

[image]

When I try to remove the relationship between the two tables, all the `stud_id` is properly inserting/adding. Can someone tell me what's my error? Thank you

Here's my code for inserting the data

```
    for($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++){
          if($row['studentid'][$x] == 0){ 
                 $stud_id= NULL;
                 $name  = $row['name'][$x];
          }else{
                 $stud_id= $row['studentid'][$x];
                 $name  = NULL;
          }

          $query= $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO officers_tbl (name, student_id) 
                        VALUES (:name, :student_id);

           $query->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
           $query->bindParam(':student_id', $stud_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
           $query->execute();

    }
```

**It's working now. I restarted my laptop.**

Comment: _submitting the form_ -- and what is your form and processing code? did a great job explaining the problem, but utter lack of code for us to look at and help diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what are you trying to do when you say:

> When stud_id = 0, insert student name to officer_name and NULL to student_id. 
>   When stud_id != 0, insert NULL to name and stud_id in student_id.

If works fine when you remove the relationship. I think the problem could be in the order your are doing the SQL inserts. The inserts in student_tbl must come first or be sure that the students_id exists.

Maybe "stud_id = 0" means that there's a new student that have no "stud_id" yet, and you try to insert a NULL instead a valid stud_id.

```
[http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp][1]
```

The FOREIGN KEY constraint prevents invalid data from being inserted into the foreign key column, because it has to be one of the values contained in the table it points to.